# Memory leak with getline C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, getline

I am trying to parse a config file with getline but sometimes I have a memory leak and sometimes not.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include "parser.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct global parse_global(char *line, FILE *file)
{
    char *log_file = NULL;
    bool log = false;
    char *pid_file = NULL;

    size_t len;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *saveptr = NULL;

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1
           && strcmp(line, "[[vhosts]]\n") != 0)
    {
        char *arg_name = strtok_r(line, " =", &saveptr);
        char *arg_value = strtok_r(NULL, " =\n", &saveptr);

        if (strcmp(arg_name, "log_file") == 0)
        {
            log_file = strdup(arg_value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "log") == 0)
        {
            if (strcmp(arg_value, "true") == 0)
            {
                log = true;
            }
            else
            {
                log = false;
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "pid_file") == 0)
        {
            pid_file = strdup(arg_value);
        }
    }

    return global_init(log_file, log, pid_file);
}

struct vhost parse_vhost(char *line, FILE *file)
{
    char *server_name = "my_server";
    char *port = NULL;
    char *ip = NULL;
    char *root_dir = NULL;
    char *default_file = NULL;

    size_t len;
    ssize_t nread;
    char *saveptr = NULL;

    while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1
           && strcmp(line, "\n") != 0)
    {
        char *arg_name = strtok_r(line, " =", &saveptr);
        char *arg_value = strtok_r(NULL, " =\n", &saveptr);

        if (strcmp(arg_name, "server_name") == 0)
        {
            server_name = strdup(arg_value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "port") == 0)
        {
            port = strdup(arg_value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "ip") == 0)
        {
            ip = strdup(arg_value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "root_dir") == 0)
        {
            root_dir = strdup(arg_value);
        }
        else if (strcmp(arg_name, "default_file") == 0)
        {
            default_file = strdup(arg_value);
        }
    }
    
    return vhost_init(server_name, port, ip, root_dir, default_file);
}

void free_global(struct global g)
{
    free(g.pid_file);
    free(g.log_file);
}

void free_vhost(struct vhost v)
{
    free(v.server_name);
    free(v.port);
    free(v.ip);
    free(v.root_dir);
    free(v.default_file);
}

struct server *fileconfig_parser(char *file)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(file, "r");
    if (!f)
    {
        perror("cannot open file");
        return NULL;
    }

    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    ssize_t nread = getline(&line, &len, f);
    if (nread == -1 || strcmp(line, "[global]\n") != 0)
    {
        free(line);
        perror("invalid file");
        fclose(f);
        return NULL;
    }

    struct global global = parse_global(line, f);
    if (global.pid_file == NULL)
    {
        free_global(global);
        fclose(f);
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }

    struct vhost vhost = parse_vhost(line, f);
    if (vhost.server_name == NULL || vhost.port == NULL || vhost.ip == NULL
        || vhost.root_dir == NULL)
    {
        free_global(global);
        free_vhost(vhost);
        fclose(f);
        free(line);
        return NULL;
    }

    struct server *server = server_init(global, vhost);

    free(line);
    fclose(f);

    return server;
}
```

The memory come from the line allocated by getline but sometimes when I run the programme there is no memory leak and I dont know why.
It seems to me that I free line in every cases.

I also don’t know why it happened randomly.

```
=================================================================
==1561==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 120 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fad2918a808 in __interceptor_malloc ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:144
    #1 0x7fad28f0e543 in _IO_getdelim /build/glibc-SzIz7B/glibc-2.31/libio/iogetdelim.c:62
    #2 0x7ffde0365e1f  ([stack]+0x1ee1f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 120 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show the verbatim ouput of your leak detector.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man docs,

> `getline()`  reads an entire line from stream, storing the address of the buffer containing the text into `*lineptr`. The buffer is
> null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.
>
> If `*lineptr` is set to `NULL` and `*n` is set 0 before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a  buffer  for storing the line. This buffer
> should be freed by the user program even if `getline()` failed.

This means that you have to explicitly call `free()` even if you never directly malloc'ed.

Refer to this example given in the man pages

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        FILE *stream;
        char *line = NULL;
        size_t len = 0;
        ssize_t nread;

        if (argc != 2)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <file>\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        stream = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (stream == NULL)
        {
                perror("fopen");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stream)) != -1)
        {
                printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", nread);
                fwrite(line, nread, 1, stdout);
        }

        free(line);
        fclose(stream);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: True, but this answer is not complete.  The code posted in the question will fail with a corrupted heap if the `getline()` calls in `parse_global()` or `parse_vhost()` reallocate `line`.  Note that `line` **is** freed in `fileconfig_parser()`.

Comment: If the question weren't so convoluted, it would be easier to give a clear answer to it.